# loginWithUser:user to QBChat instance in iOS Fail

Tags: quickblox

When I tray to connect the device for chat, after a success login, the response is Unauthorised. Im coding like in the sample that comes with SDK.  is:

```
-(void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result  context:(void *)contextInfo{


if([result isKindOfClass:[QBUUserLogInResult class]]){

    // Success result
    if(result.success){

        QBUUserLogInResult *res = (QBUUserLogInResult *)result;
        [self saveHostUser:res.user];
        [self loginResult:kLoggedOnline andErrorDescription:nil];

        // Login to Chat
        [QBChat instance].delegate = self;
        [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:[[[UserService sharedInstance] hostUser] qbUser]];

        // Register as subscriber for Push Notifications
        [QBMessages TRegisterSubscriptionWithDelegate:nil];
    }
}

}
```

The error retrieved is:

```
error:
2013-03-29 16:51:37.201 App[2031:720f] didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
2013-03-29 16:51:37.201 App[2031:680b] QBChat/xmppStreamDidNotAuthenticate: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized></not-authorized></failure>
2013-03-29 16:51:37.201 App[2031:730b] redelegateBackCurrentApplication
2013-03-29 16:51:37.302 App[2031:720f] QBChat/xmppStreamDidDisconnect, error=(null)
```

So, the messages are not sent. Does anyone know what else I need than session, login, register, getting user.

Answer (score 0):

You should set password

```
res.user.password = @"yourpassword";
[self saveHostUser:res.user];
```